Plotting arrows with plotly
I'm trying to plot arrows with plotly's graph object package using plotly.graph_objects.Scatter but couldn't figure out how to set the right parameters in order to show only arrows on one end of the line:
 fig_chips.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0,1,0,2,0,1], y=[0,1,0,1,0,0], mode="lines+markers",
        marker= dict(size=10,symbol= "arrow", angleref="previous")))

At the moment the x and y coordinates always showing back to (0,0) as an "workaround" leading to the following plot:
So, my question is there are more elegant solution to plot arrowas with plotly's graph object package or plotly in general?

How do we reproduce your issue?

You can do this this way:
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
  x=[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1],
  y=[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  mode="lines+markers",
  marker=dict(size=10),
  line=dict(width=2),
  name='Lines'
))

arrows = [
  dict(
    x=1, y=1, xref="x", yref="y",
    ax=0, ay=0, axref="x", ayref="y",
    showarrow=True, arrowhead=2, arrowsize=1, arrowwidth=2, arrowcolor="red"
  ),
  dict(
    x=2, y=1, xref="x", yref="y",
    ax=0, ay=0, axref="x", ayref="y",
    showarrow=True, arrowhead=2, arrowsize=1, arrowwidth=2, arrowcolor="blue"
  ),
  dict(
    x=1, y=0, xref="x", yref="y",
    ax=0, ay=0, axref="x", ayref="y",
    showarrow=True, arrowhead=2, arrowsize=1, arrowwidth=2, arrowcolor="green"
  )
]

for arrow in arrows:
  fig.add_annotation(arrow)

fig.update_layout(
  title="Plot with Lines and Arrows",
  xaxis_title="X Axis",
  yaxis_title="Y Axis",
  showlegend=True
)

fig.show()

which gives you


Any ideas for making this faster when there are many points and arrows?

Thanks Serge, that helped me a lot... Not sure how long the solution with annotation would take but for many data points I found out you can insert 'None' after every coordinate tuple, e.g.:
x=[0,1,None,0,2,None,0,1], y=[0,1,None,0,1,None,0,0]  

